# Java xerces DocumentBuilderFactoryimpl not found - What to do?

Tags: java, jboss, xerces

I get this message :

> javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError:
>   Provider
>   org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImp

but i can't seem to solve the problem. I have googled, but can't find any good solutions.

Does anyone have an idea of what could be wrong?
And maybe how to solve it :)

Answer (score 4):

The `org.apache.xerces` is from the [Apache Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/) package, and something in your application has a dependency on it. Try downloading it (latest version is 2.9.0) and adding it to your application's classpath.

Comment: I did download Apache Xerces, and it broke everything. Problem is that I have a set of JAR files that I control, but another set of JAR Files outside of my control.

Answer (score 1):

[DocumentBuilderFactory](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html) has a multi-step process for finding the actual parser implementation, as described in the linked JavaDoc. Your error message is almost certainly coming from there.

I suspect that your JBoss startup script is setting the `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory` system property incorrectly (I've seen this happen before, used to avoid a bug in the released library). I would start by grepping the JBoss configuration directory for that property, followed by explicitly setting the `jaxp.debug` property (also described in the link). Assuming that your startup script is indeed explicitly setting the property, find out who made that change and ask him/her if you can delete it (or to provide you with the correct JARs if not).

Answer (score 0):

As you've tagged your question JBoss, I'll assume your code is running in the JBoss container.

JBoss may have already loaded a version of Xerces for it's own use and you're trying to load a different version in your code (either explicitly or through some dependency) and the configuration for your version is not compatible with the version that's already loaded.

This [JIRA Ticket on JBoss.or](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBAS-3248)g suggests deleting the xercesimpl.jar in jasperserver/WEB-INF/lib folder to allow your version to be used.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.
I am running the code in the JBoss container.
I must also add that i am pretty new to JBoss. I can't find the folder "jasperserver/WEB-INF/lib" in my JBoss folder, but it can locate the file "xercesimpl.jar" in jboss/lib/endorsed.

Do you think it is any luck with deleting that file?